# Realtime data with websocket

Tags: javascript, api, websocket

I am trying to get the Real time data from cryptocurrecy API (min-api.cryptocompare.com/data) via using websocket but unfortunately, I am getting below error

> : failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

I am able to get the data from API via axios and render it on UI.

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
 import axios from 'axios';

 // using websocket to get the live data
 var exampleSocket = new WebSocket('wss://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,DASH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR');

 exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log('event.data', event.data);
 }

 class App extends Component {

  state = {
    persons: []
   }    
     componentDidMount() {
         console.log('DidMount');
        axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,DASH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR`)
        .then(res => {
          const persons = res.data;
          this.setState({ persons });
       })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
     });
   }
 render() {
  return (
      <div>App </div>
      )
  }
 };
 export default App;
```

I need to render the live data into my UI without any user event. 
Just like share market app.

this is just demo application so can also use different real time 
data provider API for solution.

Thanks

Comment: This could be the reason: https://community.c9.io/t/connecting-to-websockets-results-in-502-bad-gateway/229

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you please help me to get another Realtime data API for testing purpose with websocket protocol. Cheers !!!